# How to use native variables behind webpack?

Tags: webpack

I want to have a small section of my code using the 'real' `require` method, is there any way to do something like

```
const _require = WebpackReplaced.require
```

which can then be indexed for things like the cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is a use case for webpack externals - https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

To get this particular problem working, I placed

```
{
  externals: {
    require: "require"
  }
}
```

in  the webpack configuration. This means you can reference the true variable using

```
const _require = require("require")
```